# Distortion function from K Means of Scikit-Learn

Tags: python, k-means, scikit-learn

To get distortion function (sum of distance for each point to its center) when doing K means clustering by Scikit-Learn, one simple way is just to get the centers (`k_means.cluster_centers_`) and sum up the distance for each point.

Just wondering if there is a faster way? (In terms of programmer time) Something like a direct function call or so.

Comment: I'm guessing there is, since getting the cluster centers implies summing the distances anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is already pre-computed at `fit` time in the `inertia_` attribute for the `KMeans` class.

```
>>> from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
>>> from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
>>> iris = load_iris()
>>> km = KMeans(3).fit(iris.data)
>>> km.inertia_
78.940841426146108
```

Comment: Check cluster sizes too, `np.bincount(km.labels_)` -- if they're badly unbalanced, you have a problem. (How many clusters do you have ?)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the definition of distortion measure,it can either be

> **Sum** of the square of the distance
> of each example to its nearest cluster center.

OR

> **Average** of the euclidean squared distance from the centroid of the respective clusters.

For the latter case,you can visit
[Can distortion be derived from inertia rather than recalculating it from scratch in case of kmeans?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/89960/can-distortion-be-derived-from-inertia-rather-than-recalculating-it-from-scratch)

The **inertia_** attribute in KMeans is defined in [official docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) as

> Sum of squared distances of samples to their closest cluster center,
> weighted by the sample weights if provided.